# How to submit a "underling" form from a dialog window with modal confirmation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, jquery-ui

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.9 and jQuery Rails 2.1.4. I have a form for which a confirmation message is displayed when the user changes a radio button and, if the user confirms that action, then the form is submitted. The related JavaScript code is the following:

```
radioButtons.change(function() {
  var confirm_submit = confirm('Are you sure?');

  if (confirm_submit) {
    // Submit the form
    var form = $jQ(radioButtonContainer).closest('form');
    form.submit();
  } else {
    // Do nothing
  }
})
```

I would like to replace the alert message with a [dialog window with modal confirmation](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) containing `Confirm` and `Cancel` buttons behaving as the following:

1. when the `Cancel` button is clicked then the dialog window is closed and nothing more happens;
2. when the `Confirm` button is clicked then the dialog window is closed and the "underling" form is submitted.

How can I make that?

Comment: there are lots of jQuery modal alert/confirm plugins, including jQueryUI  http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation. Just wire the buttons to your form submit

Comment: How to "just wire the buttons to your form submit"?

Comment: look at `view source` in demo link, look at buttons object and their callbacks. Put your form submit in callback for applicable button